# Conrtoller for "right answer"

Tags: python, django

I'm developing project like http://stackoverflow.com. So, like questions and answers. I'm trying to find out realization of "right answer". I'm using Django.
Here is model for "Answer":

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=datetime.now())
    is_right = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ratio = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, default=0)
```

I'm interested in controller to define the "right answer" and "on HTML-page" realization.

Comment: How would you mark answer as right?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for. What is a "controller to define the right answer"? What should it do? The right answer is defined right there in your model.

Comment: If you have a one-to-many (q-to-a) relationship with one being special, you should not define this as a property on the many-side (answer), but on the one-side (question). It's perfectly possible in your example to have multiple is_right answers.

Comment: Don't call the `datetime.now()` funcion in your model. You'll find out that all Answers created will have the date of the server startup time. Instead, do this: `date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=datetime.now)`.

Comment: Thanks for all of you.
I meant controller in MVC model.

Comment: @gertvdij, thanks. I got your point. I'll rewrite my code. Your advise is very helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a controller to mark an answer right can be as simple as

```
def mark_right(answer_id):
  try:
    answer = Answer.objects.get(pk=answer_id)
  except Answer.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
  answer.is_right = True
  answer.save()
```

Additionally, askbot is a fully functional stackoverflow clone, written in django https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel